# git tortoise:2.1 error code 128, "fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly"

Tags: git, tortoisesvn

[image]

The above picture lasted for a long time, and the result is shown in the figure below

[image]

*PS: When I push less than 4 files will be success, I don't know how happened.However there are thousands of documents...*

- **The first**, I think the problem is `git config http.postBuffer`. Then 1GB postBuffer config and it invalid.
- **Second**, I thought it was the Internet speed problem. So I configured git's minimum speed and minimum speed time 0, 999999.The depressing thing is that it still can't.
- **Third**, I tried to unload and reload tortoise 2.1, and it didn't change.
- **Fourth**, I am I'm trying to upgrade the tortoise  version.

**Keywords**: ssh, gitlab, local push to remote, target project size less than 10M, Internet speed 10Mb/s+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustrated [in this thread](https://discourse.ros.org/t/access-problems-to-gitlab-and-github-from-china/10278/4), accessing GitLab from China can be an hit or miss.

That is why certain projects like autoware have a [gitee mirror](https://gitee.com/autowarefoundation/autoware), with [Gitee](https://gitee.com/about_us) being local to China.

Since it is actually an on-premise GitLab instance, the [OP renzhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14337450/renzhan) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64057081/git-tortoise2-1-error-code-128-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly/64058842?noredirect=1#comment113281868_64058842):

> the original is the company's public network gateway problem,
> => change to the intranet address.

Comment: I use gitlab which is built under the LAN.
Then I don't know what happened. At first, I could pull and push several files, but now none of them is available

Comment: @renzhan So a private on-premise GitLab instance? Maybe some firewall rules have changed?

Comment: Looking for a day's problem, finally learned from other places. The original problem is that somethings wrong  with the company's public network gateway. I changed the IPv4 address, then git to be OK! Finally, I don't have to see the red color. The green of success makes people relaxed and happy! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @renzhan Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.